# Java servlet for upload image

Tags: java, web-applications

I would like to create a [Java Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) to allow an Android device to post photos. Where should I begin? Should I use the Apache common fileupload library?

I know how to create a servlet, basically like this right:

```
@WebServlet(name = "UploadServlet")
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

(I'm new to Java and web development.)

Comment: Tks for the question redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're using Servlet API 3.0, so there is a dedicated annotation for tagging methods which manage file upload: `javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig`.

A good tutorial / example is *[How to write upload file servlet with Servlet 3.0 API](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/how-to-write-upload-file-servlet-with-servlet-30-api)*.